# Bitmap operations in background thread makes UI unresponsive

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio, android-progressbar

I am running following operations in the background thread:

1. Store byte image data locally as a jpeg.
2. Fetch that image as a bitmap.
3. Run face-detection algorithm and fetch facial points
4. Place an overlay according to those points
5. And finally save that bitmap again.

While performing these operations, I am displaying a progress bar. But the progress bar animation gets stuck i.e it becomes unresponsive until the thread completes its work(update: nothing in the whole UI seems to function while the background work is running).

Doesn't this make actual intentions of using background thread obsolete?

What approach should I take to overcome this problem?

My code is:

```
  //Show ProgressBar
  Runnable worker = () -> {

      //My Operations

     runOnUiThread(() -> {

             //Hide ProgressBar

          });
    }
```

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: Use RxJava for the background process.

Comment: @Jaymin how would that make a difference after all Rxjava uses threads as well

Comment: where did you start progress bar ?

Comment: can you assure you are not running background thread in Main UI thread?

Comment: @HemantParmar just before starting the thread

Comment: @madroid yes. Running all these operations in Main UI would make the app show the "app not responding" message. Especially on low end phones

Comment: may be this reason cause, start progress bar inside background thread if you are using asynctask than in `onPreExecute()` i was facing same issue.

Comment: Bitmap processing is kind of complex use case. in that case, RxJava will help. You need to process bitmap in background thread and handle progress on Main thread. Image processing is expensive on Main thread.

Comment: @Yo'dilawar have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8322396/5110595)

Comment: why don't you create a service and do everything there?

Comment: @HemantParmar check my code above. I am updating my view on Main UI thread

Comment: @madroid wouldn't that make my already complex code more complicated, I would have to setup BroadcastListener to listen the process completion

Comment: @Mr.Roshan check out.

Comment: @HemantParmar I was doing exactly that before. But the issue was AsyncTask was taking a little more time that regular thread due to the fact that AsyncTask has lower priority than regular thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the async approach, it will work

```
 private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Progress, Bitmap> {
 protected void onPreExecute() {
     // Runs on the UI thread before doInBackground

     progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
 }

 protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
     // Some long-running task like downloading an image.
     // convert your bitmap
     return someBitmap;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress... values) {
  //update progress
 }  

 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
     //hide progress bar
 }}
```

Comment: I was doing this very thing previously. But I found out that asyncTask is comparatively slower than regular thread. Because thread priority under the hood is greater for regular thread than asynctask